# Best practice git merging two branches with many changes

Tags: git, merge, fetch

We are currently developing a new feature for an open-source project and therefore checkedout the master, and did a lot of chnages over the past months ( > 400 commits). Now we want to merge it upstream/master to build a final version.

The question we are facing now is, what is the best way to do the merge with upstream master?

> $ git fetch upstream
>
> $ git merge upstream/master

or

> $ git rebase upstream/master

or something diffrent like git pull?

The main target should be to have to changes things multiple times.

Comment: There's what you want the resulting history to look like, and how you're going to resolve the accumulated conflicts -- 400 unmerged changes on your side and _how_ many on the other?.  Those are two separate questions.

Comment: Note that `git pull` is just a convenience method for running `git fetch` followed immediately by `git merge` or `git rebase`.  In that sense there's no difference, but in another, there is: you probably want to git fetch, then *look*, and only *then* decide how to combine (one big merge, several little merges, whatever).  That turns `git pull` into an "inconvenience" instead of a convenience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend `git pull`; `fetch` followed by either `merge` or `rebase` is generally safer as you can preview what will happen next by comparing `master` and `origin/master`.

The decision to use `merge` or `rebase` might not be yours to make. Does the upstream repository have contribution guidelines? If so, you should follow those.

If the upstream repository has no contribution guidelines then either a `merge` or a `rebase` may be appropriate.

But based on this

> We are currently developing a new feature for an open-source project...

I understand that there are multiple people working on this feature, and thus multiple copies of your repository. In this case I would *strongly recommend against using `rebase`*. This would cause your commit hashes to change, and can cause lots of difficulty. As a general rule, **don't rewrite shared history**.

So you're left with `merge`, which is probably what I would use in this situation.